# systemd timer for target that calls template

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have a systemd template, `load@.service` defined as:

```
[Unit]
Description=load script
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
PartOf=load.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 load -d %i
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I need to run four different instances of this script with different parameters for `-d`, so I have set up a `load.target` defined as:

```
[Unit]
Description=dataloader.load workers
Wants=load@1.service load@2.service load@3.service load@4.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want each of the four instances to run every 10 minutes.

How can I set up a systemd timer to invoke the `.target` at an interval?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer unit `load@.timer` defined as:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run load@.service every 10 minutes

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/10
AccuracySec=1us
```

And modify `load.target` to invoke the `.timer` units instead of the `.service` units:

```
[Unit]
Description=dataloader.load workers
Wants=load@1.timer load@2.timer load@3.timer load@4.timer

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```